# How to calculate periodIds using SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a `table1` which stores the data for multiple dates say (between `2022-01-01` to `2022-01-10`) and I have another `table2` which has time interval and has every 5mins information of dates available in `table1` (i.e. 288 records for each day in above table).

Now, How I can write a query for `table 2` to calculate time interval for each specific date in `table 1`. Say I need time intervals between

```
2022-01-01 12:00:00 to 2022-01-01 02:00:00
2022-01-02 00:05:00 to 2022-01-02 23:00:00
2022-01-04 00:05:00 to 2022-01-10 15:00:00
```

I tried using `DATEDIFF` function but that is not giving the results. let's say If I take date `2022-01-02 00:00:00` then my time interval should go back to 1 it should be 2 for `2022-01-02 00:05:00`

Below is the example of data:

Table 1:
ID                Start date          End date
20030917.D0001  2003-09-17 14:10:00 2003-09-18 14:20:00

Table 2:
Date       Time interval    Amount
2003-09-17   1                150
2003-09-17   2                100
2003-09-17   3                200

---

2003-09-17   288              250
2003-09-18   1                250
2003-09-18   2                300
2003-09-18   3                1100

---

2003-09-18   288              150

The time interval in table 2 is every 5 mins of that particular date. Now I need to fetch the data from table 2 which matches with specific date and time in table1

Comment: Post your `CREATE TABLE` statements and show us your actual data in each table - ideally post a DBFiddle or SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing here, if you are looking to return data from table2 with specific time and the table formatted like below

table1

| tbl1id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | 2022-01-10 |

table2

| tbl2id | tbl1id | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 12:05:00 |
| 3 | 1 | 12:10:00 |

your query should be

```
select * 
from table2 
where Time between '12:00:00' and '02:00:00'
and tbl1id 
in
(
select tbl1id
from table1
where Date = '2022-01-01'
)
```

however it you  are looking for just looking for calculate time interval in Minute

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME2 = '2022-01-02 00:00:00';  
DECLARE @enddate   DATETIME2 = '2022-01-02 00:05:00'; 
SELECT DATEDIFF(Minute, @startdate, @enddate);
```

that should do it.

Comment: Got the info, I used DATEDADD and created separate  column and joined the two tables.
DATEADD(minute,5*PERIODID,DATE) as Calculated_datetime